# Using SortOption in Fulltext Search in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

This is how I add document to index:

```
Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
    .setId( user.getEmailAddress() )
        .addField( Field.newBuilder().setName( "lastLogin" ).setDate( Field.date(user.getLastLogin()) ) )
        .build();
```

I want to sort by `lastLogin` property so I tried:

```
SortOptions sortOption = SortOptions.newBuilder()
        .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder()
                .setExpression("lastLogin")
                .setDefaultValueNumeric(0))
                .build();

QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
        .setLimit( SEARCH_RESULT )
        .setOffset( offset )
        .setSortOptions( sortOption )
        .build();
```

Am I using `SortOptions` correctly? Result set are not what I expected when using with offset.

Comment: Can you post what you expect to get and what are you getting?

Comment: One problem is that offset is not working properly.

Comment: You need to be more specific in order for us to help you.

Comment: The problem occurs only in development server, but when deployed, it works perfectly. In development server, `cursor` and `offset` may not work as expected, both in `Java` and `Python`. Thanks